# Custom theme of all dialogs in an app

Tags: android, styles, android-dialog, android-theme

Is there any similar theme generator as [HoloColors](http://android-holo-colors.com/) or [Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) which would help us change theme of Dialogs and AlertDialogs in our apps?

My app uses Holo theme and I managed to change style of views such as EditTexts and Buttons but they remain unchanged when they appear in a Dialog. I would also like to change color of the blue line under a title.

I've found a few question and answers related to this topic but they practically say it's not even possible. I cannot believe it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

At least for the AlertDialog it is possible. here i posted my solution of a function which is called at some point (for example button click) in your code and creates an alert dialog own layout over your screen.. the layout is a normal layout.xml which you can define the way you want. works perfect for me!

```
private void showAddUserGeneratedStationDialog() {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                AmplifyActivity.this);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

            //inflate your layout.xml
        alertDialog
                .setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_station, null));

            //show dialog over activity screen
        final AlertDialog ad = alertDialog.show();

            //put actions to your ui-elements
        Button cancelBtn = (Button) ad
                .findViewById(R.id.list_user_generated_cancelBU);
        cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ad.cancel();
            }
        });

        Button doneBtn = (Button) ad
                .findViewById(R.id.list_user_generated_doneBU);
        doneBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                            //get sth from your layout f.e. some textInput
                String stationUrl = ((TextView) ad
                        .findViewById(R.id.list_user_generated_stationURLInput))
                        .getText().toString();

                    // did some other things

                ad.dismiss();

            }
        });

    }
```

and my layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_user_generated_addStationDialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#99000000"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/list_user_generated_cancelBU"
                style="@style/ButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|right"
                android:text="@string/cancel" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/AmplifyHeadlineElement"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/list_userGenerated_addStation" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/list_user_generated_doneBU"
                style="@style/ButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|right"
                android:text="@string/done" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/list_user_generated_stationURLInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/list_userGenerated_addUrlExample"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" >
        </EditText>

        <!-- MORE BUT I DELETED  IT FOR BETTER OVERVIEW -->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```